# Is there alternative str.find in c++?

Tags: c++, string, find

I have got a queue fifo type (first in, first out) with strings in it. Every string is sentence. I need to find a word in it, and show it on console. The problem is, that when i used str.find("word") it can showed sentence with "words".

Add white space and some symbols like ".,?!" = str.find("word ") etc. but its not a solution

```
if (head != nullptr)
  do {
    if (head->zdanie_kol.find("promotion") != string::npos ||
        head->zdanie_kol.find("discount") != string::npos ||
        head->zdanie_kol.find("sale") != string::npos ||
        head->zdanie_kol.find("offer") != string::npos)
      cout << head->zdanie_kol << endl;
  } while (head != nullptr);
```

For example, i got two sentences, one is correct, another one is not.

Correct:

> We have a special OFFER for you an email database which allows to contact eBay members both sellers and shoppers.

Not Correct:

> Do not lose your chance sign up and find super PROMOTIONS we prepared for you!

Comment: There's always regex, if you want two problems. :)

Comment: Oh, joy.  Market-speak.

Comment: Or just add whitespace at both end of the search term to prevent it matching as a lesser-included substring.

Comment: Where is `head` adjusted to point to the next item in your loop?

Answer (score 4):

The three simplest solutions I can think of for this are:

1. Once you get the result simply check the next character. If it's a whitespace or `'\0'`, you found your match. Make sure to check the character before too so you don't match `sword` when looking for `word`. Also make sure you're not reading beyond the string memory.
2. Tokenize the string first. This will break the sentence into words and you can then check word by word to see if it matches. You can do this with [`strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok).
3. Use regular expression (e.g. [`regex_match()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/)) as mentioned in the comments. Depending on the engine you choose, the syntax may differ, but most of them have a something like `"\\bsale\\b"` which will match on word boundary (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/) for more information).

Comment: I like No. 1, but you may also have to consider punctuation at the end in addition to whitespace and the *nul-terminating* char.

Comment: I like the options provided, but given how many things you'd need to check for, this really does feel like a job for regex.

Comment: No. 1 is actually much simpler than described. If the match is preceded by a letter or followed by a letter it fails. Otherwise, it succeeds. +1.

Comment: +1 for some good options. Since there are several search terms I'd probably go with #2 and tokenize the string into a search friendly container like an unordered set and then perform the queries. Since this is C++ and not C I would use stringstream and a facet customized to eat any punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using `std::unordered_set` and `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
//...
std::unordered_set<std::string> filter_word = {"promotion", "discount", "sale", "offer"};
//...
std::istringstream strm(head->zdanie_kol);
std::string word;
while (strm >> word)
{
    if (filter_word(word).count())
    {
        std::cout << head->zdanie_kol << std::endl;     
        break;
    }
}  
//...
```

If you had many more words to check instead of only 4 words, this solution seems easier to use since all you have to do is add those words to the `unordered_set`.